# In Gulp, how do you minify a css file, then append it to an already minified css file?

Tags: gulp

I have a large minified css file and a small non-minified file.
I'll be changing the non-minified file regularly, but I want them combined.
However re-minifying a large minified file takes WAY too long.

What I want is something like this ...

```
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var cssjoin = require('gulp-cssjoin');

gulp.task('cssjoin', function() {
    gulp.src( 'changing.css' )
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename( 'changed.min.css' ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest( '.' ));

    gulp.src( ['big.min.css','changed.min.css'] )
        .pipe(cssjoin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest( 'final.min.css' ))
});
```

Basically, first minify the small file, then join it to the end of the large one. The code above doesn't work of course, tasks need a `return` in the function, etc.

I also want to delete 'changed.min.css' once the join is done.

I tried various combinations of things for 3 hours without finding a working solution. How would one go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-add-src`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src) to append `big.min.css` to the stream. That way you only run `cssnano()` on `changed.css`, not both files.

Afterwards you use [`gulp-concat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to combine both files into a single new `final.min.css`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');

gulp.task('cssjoin', function() {
  return gulp.src('changing.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(addsrc.append('big.min.css'))
    .pipe(concat('final.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

There's no need to delete an intermediary `changed.min.css` with this since none is written to disk. All operations occur in-memory.

Comment: You nailed it! I changed `addsrc.append` to `addsrc.prepend`, and it worked exactly as needed. Thank you :)